# не работает авторизация

Tags: веб-программирование, битрикс, авторизация

Приблизительно неделю назад на всех моих сайтах перестала работать авторизация. В лог ничего не записывается. Страница будто перезагружается, но доступ не открывается. Раньше всё работало отлично. 
В консоли только предупреждение:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure
>   context. A warning has been added to the URL bar.

При этом сайт на CMS Битрикс спокойно даёт доступ к административной части сайта.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А "все ваши сайты" размещаются в каком-то одном месте?

Comment: @Andrewus нет. Есть на jino, есть на timeweb

Answer (score 0):

Надо ставить **SSL** и переводить сайт на протокол **https**.

Comment: Ага, однако ни один из современных браузеров на данный момент не запрещает авторизовываться без https

Comment: а в чем может быть проблема, если не в отсутствии https?

Comment: @ZaynabCat извиняюсь, не до конца вчитался в описание. Если при попытке входа страница перезагружается, то рекомендую посмотреть какой редирект происходит и уже от этого отталкиваться.

Comment: @Alexandr там простая проверка. Если логин и пароль совпадают с логином и паролем из БД, то давать доступ к следующей странице

Comment: @ZaynabCat не знаток битрикса, но не очень верится в _простую проверку_. Может не пишется сессия и происходит обратно переадресация на страницу входа. Без конкретики здесь можно только догадки строить.

Comment: @AlexandrSysoev так на обычном сайте с самой простой регистрацией как раз и не работает, а в админку Битрикса заходит

Comment: Консоль что-то говорит? Может не загружаться какой-то скрипт из разряда аналитика и отсюда ошибка в скриптах, они часто этим грешат, колибри и им подобные.